# Message is cut off when sending it using Mail Core in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, mailcore

I am trying to send a message, using MailCore framework in iOS. This is my View Did Load method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

myMessage = [[CTCoreMessage alloc] init];

// Set To
CTCoreAddress *addrTo = [CTCoreAddress address];
[addrTo setEmail:@"aaa@gmail.com"];
[myMessage setTo:[NSSet setWithObject:addrTo]];

// Set From 
CTCoreAddress *addrFrom = [CTCoreAddress address];
[addrFrom setEmail:@"bbb@gmail.com"];
[addrFrom setName:@"bb"];
[myMessage setFrom:[NSSet setWithObject:addrFrom]];

[myMessage setSubject:@"test"];
[myMessage setHTMLBody:@"Отправил это сообщение через SMTP с TSL (используя MailCore) :)"];

[CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:myMessage server:@"smtp.gmail.com" username:@"bbbb"
                     password:@"ccc" port:587 useTLS:YES useAuth:YES];
[myMessage release];
}
```

As a result I get an e-mail, that is shortened for some reason like this:

```
Отправил это сообщение через SMTP с T
```

What could be the reason. I use gmail.com with port 587 and useTLS = YES, as you can see.

PS When I use mail.ru instead of gmail.com it's the same. Seems, it's not server problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems very suspiciously like an encoding issue. What if you HTML-escape your non-ascii characters first?

To clarify, it seems like someone is asking the HTMLBody for its length (which is in characters) and then assuming that's the right number of UTF-8 bytes to send.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Does anybody know, what exactly should I do to be able to send Russian text?

Comment: It might be a bug in MailCore; perhaps you could file a bug report. If it's actually HTML you're sending, you could also just escape the russian characters before passing them along (ie "э" would be "&x044D;")

Comment: Jesse, look at my next post. Here is the solution for non ASC II chars.

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest version of MailCore. Here is the commit https://github.com/mronge/MailCore/commit/1d833fb5996e2350aeaba9a1f04acb33b7cae84c

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after hours of trying, I solved this problem.

This method in libEtPan should be changed like this:

```
    int mailmime_set_body_text(struct mailmime * build_info,
               char * data_str, size_t length)
{
  int encoding;
  struct mailmime_data * data;

  encoding = mailmime_transfer_encoding_get(build_info->mm_mime_fields);

  // Added by Dennis !!!Here Russian message was cut off!!!
    // The reason is that size_t length is a count of chars but used for data length (which is twice as count of chars in UTF-8)
    // That's why I take the lenght of actual data_str, not length
    if (encoding == 2) {
        length = strlen(data_str);
    }

  data = mailmime_data_new(MAILMIME_DATA_TEXT, encoding,
               0, data_str, length, NULL);
  if (data == NULL)
    return MAILIMF_ERROR_MEMORY;

  build_info->mm_data.mm_single = data;

  return MAILIMF_NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Have you filed raise this with the libEtPan folks?

Comment: Yes, there is one more solution of this issue. Here I added some code to libEtPan, but it is possible to solve it via MailCore also. See my next post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution from the author of libEtPan Dinh Viet Hoa:

The issue is rather in this method (CTMIME_HtmlPart.m) :

```
- (struct mailmime *)buildMIMEStruct {
    struct mailmime_fields *mime_fields;
    struct mailmime *mime_sub;
    struct mailmime_content *content;
    struct mailmime_parameter *param;
    int r;

    /* text/html part */
    //TODO this needs to be changed, something other than 8BIT should be used
    mime_fields = mailmime_fields_new_encoding(MAILMIME_MECHANISM_8BIT);
    assert(mime_fields != NULL);

    content = mailmime_content_new_with_str("text/html");
    assert(content != NULL);

    param = mailmime_parameter_new(strdup("charset"), strdup(DEST_CHARSET));
    assert(param != NULL);

    r = clist_append(content->ct_parameters, param);
    assert(r >= 0);

    mime_sub = mailmime_new_empty(content, mime_fields);
    assert(mime_sub != NULL);
    NSString *str = [self content];
    //TODO is strdup necessary?
    r = mailmime_set_body_text(mime_sub, strdup([str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]), [str length]);
    assert(r == MAILIMF_NO_ERROR);
    return mime_sub;
}
```

You can see that you pass [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]as argument.
and instead of passing the size of that data, you pass [str length], which is the number of characters of that string.
Here what you should do:

```
NSData * data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8String];
r = mailmime_set_body_text(mime_sub, strdup([data bytes]), [data length]);
```